# Word search puzzle - the exact character can appear only in one word

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve a word search puzzle, however, I'm not sure what is the most efficient way to do it. I know how to [search a word in a 2D grid of characters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-a-word-in-a-2d-grid-of-characters/), but I have an extra condition that the exact character can appear only in one word (see the image below - word jp marked in red cannot be there because letter j is already a part of the word gj and p is part of the word pa. Therefore, the only possible position for word jp is (0,3),(1,3)).

One possible solution would be to store all the coordinates where the word appears in an array and then find the correct position using two for loops. However, I'm not sure whether this is the most efficient solution.

[image: Puzzle example]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make sure I understand the question - is the goal to partition the grid into horizontal, vertical, or diagonal strings with no overlap? Are there any rules governing which words are legal?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, this is the goal. The words are given in a list, and you have to find them in a grid.

Comment: Are you familiar with the exact cover problem or with the dancing links algorithm?

Comment: How big of a grid are you working with?

Comment: @templatetypedef Sorry for late reply. I was reading about the exact cover problem; however, I'm not sure how to implement it with 2D array (which represents all possible solutions for a given word - for example in the question above, the array for word jp would be {{(2,4),(3,4)},{(3,0),(3,1)}}). There is no grid limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using a solver for the exact cover problem (such as the DLX algorithm). Here's how to do it:

1. Use a regular word-search algorithm to find every copy of every word in the word list in the search grid.
2. The underlying set for the exact cover instance will contain one entry for each (x, y) position in the grid, plus one entry for each word w<sub>i</sub> that you need to search for.
3. For each location you find a word w<sub>i</sub> in the word search grid, create a set that contains w<sub>i</sub>, along with each position on the grid that you found it. So, for example, if the word w<sub>1</sub> = WORD occupied positions (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), and (3, 3), you'd make the set {w<sub>1</sub>, (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)}.

Now, an exact cover solution corresponds to

1. assigning each word to one position in the grid, since we can't use two sets that each involve the same word and have to pick at least one set per word, and
2. covering every single grid location with a word.

If you don't need that second requirement - that is, if you don't have to cover every single location in the grid with a word - you could additional add in singleton sets {(x, y)} for each position in the grid. Now, your exact cover solution will still place all the words in a way that doesn't have any overlaps, and the remaining grid locations will be covered with the singletons.

You don't have to do this with exact cover, though. You could also set up a simple backtracking recursive search in which you pick a word and, for each place you can put it, recursively try placing it there and then filling in the rest of the grid with the remaining words. Framing this as an exact cover problem is simply a way to leverage existing solvers.